# Cross-referencing with AND condition in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, cross-reference

I am trying to cross-reference from an external XML file, but instead of comparing just one key, I want to ask if one string AND other strings exist, and if yes reference from the external file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:t="http://www.tei- 
c.org/ns/1.0"
xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs t">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:param name="ids"
    select="document('instructions.xml')"/>

<xsl:key name="id" match="row" use="tokenize(normalize-space(elem[@name='Instruction']), ' ')"/>


<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node() | text() | *">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | text() | *"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="instruction">
    <xsl:for-each select=".[contains(.,key('id', ., .))]">
    <xsl:copy>     
        <xsl:attribute name="norm">
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(key('id', normalize-space(.), $ids)/elem[@name='Norm'])"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | text() | *"/>   
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Input (External File):

```
<row>
  <elem name="instruction">pour out</elem>
  <elem name="norm">p1</elem>
</row>
```

Input (File to annotate):

```
<ab type="recipe">
Bla bla
  <instruction>pour the milk out</instruction> bla
</ab>
```

Desired Output:

```
<ab type="recipe">
Bla bla
  <instruction norm="p1">pour the milk out</instruction> bla
</ab>
```

In order words: Both of the tokens in the external XML file within the element `<elem name="instruction">` "pour" AND "out" need to be contained within the `<instruction>`element in my XML file. If they are I want to set the norm attribute to the value of `<elem name="norm">` in the external file.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: As the `elem name="instruction"` element contains a list of words you tokenize, does the order of the words in the `instruction` element matter, i.e. does it have to contain the words in the same order (`pour`, `out`)?

Comment: No the order does not matter at all! "out blabla pour" should also match. However, I have the situation where I could have just "pour" with another norm value in the input data. "pour out --> p1", "pour --> p0" ..and it should first preferably match if it actually contains all of the words. So in this case p1. If it was "pour the milk" it should be p0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't work out how to do it with a key, but I did come up with an alternate approach....

```
<xsl:template match="instruction">
    <xsl:variable name="words" select="tokenize(normalize-space(.), ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="row" select="$ids//row[every $i in tokenize(normalize-space(elem[@name='instruction']), ' ') satisfies $i = $words]" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$row">
            <xsl:attribute name="norm" select="$row/elem[@name='norm']" />    
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: In response to your comment, if you can have multiple rows matching, then to get the one with the most matching words, do this....

```
<xsl:template match="instruction">
    <xsl:variable name="words" select="tokenize(normalize-space(.), ' ')" />
    <xsl:variable name="row" as="element()*">
        <xsl:perform-sort select="$ids//row[every $i in tokenize(normalize-space(elem[@name='instruction']), ' ') satisfies $i = $words]">
            <xsl:sort select="count(tokenize(normalize-space(elem[@name='instruction']), ' '))" order="descending" />
        </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="$row">
            <xsl:attribute name="norm" select="$row[1]/elem[@name='norm']" />    
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is a very nice approach! I just wanted to ask if you also had an idea how to handle situations where I have one of the same words reoccurring in the input data with another "norm":     `<row>
      <elem name="instruction">pour out</elem>
      <elem name="norm">p1</elem>
    </row>
<row>
  <elem name="instruction">pour</elem>
  <elem name="norm">p0</elem>
</row>`
With your solution I get `<instruction norm="p0 p1">` now.

Comment: Do you want to only output the first one, or the row with most words in?

Comment: the row with most matching words first. If the sentence would be "pour the milk", then it should actually be p0. but "pour the milk out" should be p1.

Comment: Thanks a looooot!

Comment: As an aside, `node()` is actually short-hand for `* | text() | comment() | processing-instruction()`, so doing `node() | text() | *` could just be shortened to `node()` anyway.